# How to know if 4 sides make a quadrangle?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a program in which you input 4 values (4 sides of a quadrangle) and it tells you if it's a square, rhombus etc. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to make the program work with values that can make a quadrangle. For example If I input 5, 5, 5, 5, it outputs that it's either a square or a rhombus. If I input 100, 1, 1, 1, it outputs another quadrangle type, but realistically you can't get a quadrangle with values like 100, 1, 1 and 1. Same goes for 9, 1, 1, 1. Is there any way to make sure that these kinds of values give out an error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make sure that these kinds of values give out an error message?

Definitely yes. In any quadrangle the longest side should be shorter than the sum of three other sides. Use this condition to check the sides.

```
bool goodQuadrangle(int sizes[4]) {
    int longest = sizes[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        if (sizes[i] > longest) {
            index = i;
            longest = sizes[i];
        }

    int sum3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (i != index)
            sum3 += sizes[i];

    return longest < sum3;
}
```